# Don't count certain columns in the "LIMIT"

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have a system where there can be "posts", "comments" to the posts, and "comments" to other comments. Think of it as a very simplified facebook comment system.

To back the data, I chose to use one table for both posts and comments, as their structure is pretty much the same:

ID (of comment or post) | TopParentID (if post, same as ID, if comment, ID of post) | DirectParentID (0 if post, either ID of post or ID of parent comment if comment) | Some more fields that are the same for both post and comments

What I'd like to achieve: Select, for example, the first 20 posts. However, with the posts, also select the comments of that post.

I know that this sounds like something where a JOIN with another table would be more optimal than having only one table, but I thought that it would be beneficial to let both posts and comments use the same ID counter, to make it easier to find both direct comments to a post, and comments to a comment of a post.

However, I do not know how to design my query with the above table design; I'd somehow need to select the first x rows where DirectParentID = 0, but also rows where TopParentID = the post id of each selected row.

Should I just change my table design after all?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Ah, sorry. Thanks for the link. I'll update it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  topParentId IN (SELECT id
                       FROM   t
                       WHERE  directParentId = 0
                              AND id <= 20);
```

`LIMIT` can't be used in sub-queries, so you would need a where clause to filter out your parent posts (maybe by date or user or something).

If you want to use limit, you can use a 'self-join' like so:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   t
        WHERE  t.did = 0
        LIMIT  20) AS t1
       INNER JOIN t
               ON t.tid = t1.id;
```

There isn't anything wrong with your design. Self referencing tables are common. You can consider your table to contain 'comment-able objects' and both comments and posts could be categorized into that. But queries which treat posts and comments as two separate entities may be more difficult/complex to create for a table treating them as a single entity (at least, that's the case for me :))

Comment: That looks like LIMIT in a subquery. Incidentally, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Yeah it's funny, I get this error if I used the first command with limit: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery. But it works alright with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you have one table for the "Thread" plus one table for "Comments".  Probably "Posts" can simply be thrown with Comments, but do not try to put Thread in also.

If you want a hierarchy (Comments to Comments), the Post should be distinguished from Comments simply by `directParentId = 0`.

If you don't want a hierarchy, then all you need is a `thread_id` on all Posts/Comments, plus a simple flag to say which is the original Post.